# Jon Bentley's bitmap sort implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bit-twiddling

I've implemented Jon Bentley's bitmap sorting algorithm from Column 1 of his Programming Pearls book. This code supports user-defined integer range (works from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), but for now only works on a distinct set of integers.

In order to avoid overflow in the integer arithmetic, I use type-casting for intermediate results.

For anyone interested, I've also posted the full description of the algorithm and performance analysis [here](http://letsalgorithm.blogspot.com/2012/02/bitmap-sort.html).

```
public int[] sortDistinctIntegers(int[] a, int min, int max){

    int N = (int)(((long)max-min) / 8 + 1);
    byte[] bitmap = new byte[N];

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        bitmap[(int)(((long)a[i]-min)/8)] |= 1 << (int)(((long)a[i]-min) % 8);

    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            if((bitmap[i] & (1 << j)) > 0){
                a[k] = i * 8 + j + min;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

I was wondering if anyone has any comments or ideas on how to improve this code (in terms of prettification, readability and performance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea: I'd try to implement the algorithm with bigger data types (`int`, `long`) instead of the `byte`.

Some notes:

1. I'd create a `BYTE_SIZE` constant for `8`, try to avoid magic numbers.

   ```
   private static final int BYTE_SIZE = 8;
   ```

   It would help a lot if you change from `byte` to another data type.
2. The return type of `sortDistinctIntegers` is really confusing. It returns with the first argument. Users easily could believe that it returns another array despite the fact that it modifies the input array. Make it `void`.
3. For easier readability I'd

   - extract out some method for easier readability: `createBitmapArray`, `processBitmapByte`, `doSort`,
   - use longer variable and parameter names (`outputIndex` instead of `k`, `bitmapSize` instead of `N`, `bitIndex` instead of `j`),
   - create local variables for `1 << bitIndex` (`mask`), etc.

Below is the code after a few refactoring steps. (I haven't checked that the algorithm is correct or not.)

```
private static final int BYTE_SIZE = 8;

public void sortDistinctIntegers(final int[] data, final int min, final int max) {
    final byte[] bitmap = createBitmapArray(data, min, max);

    doSort(data, min, bitmap);
}

private byte[] createBitmapArray(final int[] data, final int min, 
        final int max) {
    final int bitmapSize = (int) (((long) max - min) / BYTE_SIZE + 1);
    final byte[] bitmap = new byte[bitmapSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        final long min2 = (long) data[i] - min; // TODO: need a better name
        final int mask = 1 << (int) (min2 % BYTE_SIZE);
        bitmap[(int) (min2 / BYTE_SIZE)] |= mask;
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private void doSort(final int[] data, final int min, final byte[] bitmap) {
    int outputIndex = 0;
    for (int bitmapArrayIndex = 0; bitmapArrayIndex < bitmap.length; 
            bitmapArrayIndex++) {
        final byte currentBitmapByte = bitmap[bitmapArrayIndex];
        outputIndex = processBitmapByte(data, min, currentBitmapByte, 
                outputIndex, bitmapArrayIndex);
    }
}

private int processBitmapByte(final int[] data, final int min, 
        final byte currentBitmapByte, int outputIndex,
        final int bitmapArrayIndex) {
    for (int bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < BYTE_SIZE; bitIndex++) {
        final int mask = 1 << bitIndex;
        final boolean flagSet = (currentBitmapByte & mask) > 0;
        if (flagSet) {
            data[outputIndex] = bitmapArrayIndex * BYTE_SIZE + bitIndex + min;
            outputIndex++;
        }
    }
    return outputIndex;
}
```